# which is faster, left join the whole table, or left join a subselection of said table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I have two tables (A & B) my objective is to have some columns from A left joined with a few columns of B (both tables have a LOT of columns)

is it faster to :

**A) Select A -> left join -> subselect B**:
(selecting only the desired columns BEFORE the join)

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT A.col_1,A.col_2,A.col3,A.col_b FROM A
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT B.col_1,B.col_2,B.col_a FROM B) B_temp
    ON A.col_b = B_temp.col_a
```

**B) Select A -> left join -B**:
(selecting only the desired columns AFTER the join)

```
SELECT A.col_1,A.col_2,A.col3,B.col_1,B.col_2 FROM A
LEFT JOIN B
ON A.col_b = B_temp.col_a
```

My gut tells me even tho the second option is way more readable, it might be worse since it first aglutinates everything moving a lot of data around. My consideration for this is:

1. If the left join returns many results the simple-trivial approach (option B) might have to carry all these extra unecessary columns

Am I going in the right-way towards optimizing this sql query ?

Comment: *is it faster to...* Well, you try both and see. SQL is a declarative language and different query engines have different / optimised ways of performing a query.

Comment: Each make and version of database server handles this differently. Please [edit] your question to add a [tag](//stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database you use. [tag:postgresql]? [tag:mysql]? [tag:sql-server]? [tag:oracle]? [tag:google-bigquery]? [tag:amazon-redshift]? Another? And, about [tag:query-optimization], please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.

Comment: I just read the guide and figured there is some work to do before asking the question (such as query plan, i need to learn what it means), should I "halt" the question until I make it?

Comment: Since you're using SQL Server you have one of the best visual execution plan representations available, you'll see they are identical; just use your second query.

Answer (score 1):

Unless your SQL software is old and moldy, its query planner will handle your two example queries the same way.